# Getting the Mouse Movement Direction with javascript

Tags: javascript

Why this code is not working? What is the "e" parameter in the getMouseDirection function? What is the value of this e parameter?

```js
var bodyElement = document.querySelector("body");
bodyElement.addEventListener("mousemove", getMouseDirection, false);

var xDirection = "";
var yDirection = "";

var oldX = 0;
var oldY = 0;

function getMouseDirection(e) {
    //deal with the horizontal case
    if (oldX < e.pageX) {
        xDirection = "right";
    } else {
        xDirection = "left";
    }

    //deal with the vertical case
    if (oldY < e.pageY) {
        yDirection = "down";
    } else {
        yDirection = "up";
    }

    oldX = e.pageX;
    oldY = e.pageY;

    console.log(xDirection + " " + yDirection);
}
```

Comment: `e` is the window eventObject which contains the information about the mouse related events in this case. The code is working. Check the height of your body element.

Comment: The code is working fine. [Try it here](https://playcode.io/).